# Patent applications upon leaving a company

Tags: united-states, human-resources, bonus, intellectual-property, patent

I'm working in a large tech company in the US. I want to know in a top tech company, what will usually happen to our submitted patents when we leave the company? What happens to the bonus and the application itself?

The company pays a bonus upon filing the application. But hard to ask such questions from our own company.

Answer (score 2):

The following is based on the experience with my employer, but I guess it is standard practice.

When you work for a company it's usually specified in the contract that any rights on any invention, patent, etc. that you develop while working for them belongs to them.

If you leave the company you won't be able to claim any rights on any patent you contributed to. The application for the patent won't be filed under your individual name, but under the name of the company, so once you leave the process is not affected.

Regarding bonuses, it's up to the negotiation at the time when you will be leaving. Normally the process of granting the bonus takes some time from the moment the application is filed, but you should have an overview of the pending application at the time of your resignation, therefore you can bring on the table what will be done with the bonuses related to them. Of course it all depends on how the leaving happens.

Comment: At least in the US, both names are used. The inventors are listed by their names, and the employer is listed as "Assignee", meaning they get the rights to the patent.

Comment: I didn't get it. So in the US, even if I leave my name will still be on them?

Comment: @TinaJ you might be listed as inventor, but will have no rights on the patent.